# Inheritance between entities within one table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, persistence

I know the question can be simple, but, anyhow, I want to implement simple parent-child relations in one table using hibernate:

```
Parent
|       \
Child1  Child2
|           |
Junior1    Junior2
```

so it should looks like the following in the database:

```
id |  name | parent_id
1    Parent   null
2    Child1    1
3    Child2    1
4    Junior1   2
5    Junior2   3
```

In case of @Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT_CHILD")
public class ParentChild {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private String parentId; // <------ how this should be mapped?
}
```

What is the best practice on how i should map the parentId or make the following another way? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you can create a relational mapping to map within StateEntity

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private ParentChild parent;
```

in case it is a parent, then its parent can be null.

If in your project, due to performance there is case you want to load parent_id only instead of the whole ParchentChild parent instance. You can add column mapping as well

```
@Column(name="parent_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private int parentId;
```

*insertable=false, updatable=false is too make sure your system can update parent_id through @ManyToOne field only*

Comment: Hi, Le Tho! Thank you for the answer! I'm sure i will not need parent id directly since i won't get parentId but the ParentChild object. So, i guess, i require full private ParentChild parent; field, right?

Comment: Yes. then just @ManyToOne mapping is need.

Comment: when my dao trying to create it, it receives the exception: Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test_db`.`PARENT_CHILD`, CONSTRAINT `FK_5ghn6rityqie7cnwp5i5tf2ou` FOREIGN KEY (`PARENT_ID`) REFERENCES `PARENT_CHILD` (`ID`)) What that could be?